# Set the reference level of a factor in R but preserve the original ordering for graphs/charts

Tags: r, factors

I need to set the reference of my categorical variable as shown in the below code.  This allows me to set it as the base level in the lm (so i get estimates on the other two levels - setosa and virginica).  However, i'd like to preserve the original ordering in the boxplot.  That is, I need the boxplot to show the original ordering:  setosa, versicolor, virginica.  It seems R moves versicolor to the beginning in this boxplot.

```
iris1 = iris %>% mutate(Species = relevel(factor(Species),    ref="versicolor"))
boxplot(iris1$Sepal.Length~iris1$Species)
clmfit_test = lm(data=iris1,Sepal.Length ~ Species)
```

Comment: Can you change the order of commands? `boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length~iris$Species)` then change the reference level `iris1 = iris %>% mutate(Species = relevel(factor(Species), ref="versicolor"))` and use it in `lm` ?

Comment: No, because while this is a simple example, i have a a lot of graphs and charts interwoven throughout.  And I need output from the linear model to eventually go into the boxplots themselves (e.g. boxplot(predicted ~ Species)).

Comment: Can you change the levels only for `boxplot` ? `boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species, transform(iris1, Species = factor(Species, unique(Species))))`

Comment: I wound up using contrasts to set the base level.  That allowed me to preserve the ordering in the graphs.  thank you for your help.